# Why has an inertial delay with a explicitly set rejection limit different behavior when using different delays

Tags: vhdl, delay

Since VHDL-2008, it's possible to specify a different rejection time compared to the delay time if the delay model is inertial.

Inertial delay (default delay mechanism). All three signal assignments are synonymous:

```
S2 <=                        S1 after 100 ns;
S2 <=               inertial S1 after 100 ns;
S2 <= reject 100 ns inertial S1 after 100 ns;
```

The transport delay mechanism. All three signal assignments are synonymous:

```
S3 <=            transport S1 after 100 ns;
S3 <= reject 0 ns inertial S1 after 100 ns;
S3 <=                      S1'delayed(100 ns);
```

Why does the inertial delay do?
Commonly spoken: All projected waveform assignments of signal spikes shorter than the rejection limit are canceled. This is called pulse rejection.

Let's investigate inertial delays with different rejection times:

```
S1 <= '1' after 10 ns, '0' after 20 ns;

S4_inertial_5 <= reject  5 ns inertial S1 after 100 ns;  -- not filtered
S4_inertial10 <= reject 10 ns inertial S1 after 100 ns;  -- under investigation
S4_inertial20 <= reject 20 ns inertial S1 after 100 ns;  -- filtered
```

It's obvious that the 10 ns pulse is delayed to `S4_inertial_5` after 100 ns, because it filters only pulses up to 5 ns. The signal `S4_inertial20` has no events, because it gets filtered. For `S4_inertial_5`, the rejection limit is greater than the pulse width.

So lets have a closer look at:

```
S5_inertial10_after_10 <= reject 10 ns inertial S1 after  10 ns;  -- not filtered
S5_inertial10_after100 <= reject 10 ns inertial S1 after 100 ns;  -- filtered
```

Now, we see a different behavior if the delay is longer. If the delay is the same as the rejection time, the pulse gets delayed, otherwise canceled.

I tested: GHDL, ModelSim and Riviera-PRO. All show the same behavior.

My question is:
Why does pulse rejection behave differently for the same rejection limit, but for different delays? Or in other words: Is rejection an *inclusive* or *exclusive* operation and why changes *xxclusiveness* based on the total delay?

---

Here is a working testbench for own experiments:

```
entity E is
end entity;

architecture A of E is
    signal S1           : bit := '0';
    signal S2_inertial  : bit;
    signal S2_reject1   : bit;
    signal S2_reject2   : bit;
    constant LEVEL      : severity_level := ERROR; -- FAILURE;
begin
    S1 <= '1' after 10 ns, '0' after 20 ns;

    S2_inertial  <= inertial S1 after 100 ns;
    S2_reject1   <= reject 10 ns inertial S1 after 100 ns;
    S2_reject2   <= reject 10 ns inertial S1 after  10 ns;

    CheckInertial: process
    begin
        wait until S2_inertial = '1' for 200 ns;
        assert (S2_inertial = '0') report "CheckInertial: Pulse was not rejected!" severity LEVEL;
        wait;
    end process;

    CheckReject1: process
    begin
        wait until S2_reject1 = '1' for 115 ns;
        assert (S2_reject1 = '1') report "CheckReject1: Pulse has not passed rejection limit!" severity LEVEL;
        assert (now = 110 ns)     report "CheckReject1: Delayed pulse with rejection was not received at 110 ns!" severity LEVEL;
        wait;
    end process;

    CheckReject2: process
    begin
        wait until S2_reject2 = '1' for 200 ns;
        assert (S2_reject2 = '1') report "CheckReject2: Pulse has not passed rejection limit!" severity LEVEL;
        assert (now = 20 ns)      report "CheckReject2: Delayed pulse with rejection was not received at 20 ns!" severity LEVEL;
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

---

**Edit 1: Added waveform**

The following waveform shows, that `S2_reject1` (name from the testbench - equal to `S5_inertial10_after100` in the question test) has no pulse.

My expectation would be to see a delayed pulse for both signals, irrespectively of the delay length.

[image]
(clickable)

Comment: I added the waveform of the attached testbench. it shows only a pulse for the second reject signal, but not for the first. (Please note the signal names in the image match the testbench, not the questions text.) I would expect to see a pulse on `S2_reject1` too, because the rejection time is equal to `S2_reject2`.

Comment: There are 5 rules in paragraph 8, plus 2 more in para 7 of 10.5.2.2. Apply them for each new transactions on S2_reject1 for the three transactions on S1 (0, 10 and 20 ns).  An initial transaction at time 0 for S2_reject1 ('0'), provides the current value until 120 ns when the third transaction becomes the current value ('0'). The two earlier new transactions are not marked as *less than the time at which the first new transaction is projected to occur minus the pulse rejection limit* ( para 8 rule 2) and get deleted. S1 has two new transactions at the same time so they survive.

Comment: BTW the rejection time limit is specified identically to -1993 (your question first sentence) . 8.4.1 *If the delay mechanism specifies inertial delay, and if the reserved word **reject** followed by a time expression is present, then the time expression specifies the pulse rejection limit. In all other cases, the pulse rejection limit is specified by the time expression associated with the first waveform element.* -2008 10.5.2.1 para 6.

Comment: If you want to answer your question yourself (for E) show how the 5 rules in 8 affect old transactions for each new transaction on S2_reject1. The earlier snippets don't add to your question, don't teach without references, there's nothing spoken here, it's written. Pulses not 'spikes'.